# How to copy dependancies binaries with no bin folder in the SCM

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a `project A` that is dependent on other projects `B`,`C`,`D`.

If `A` changes then I want `A` to be built (Done)
Now if `B`,`C` or `D` changes I want them (the ones that changed) to be built then their binaries must be copied to `A` and then `A` must be built.

I am using the artifact plugin to copy the binaries but I do not store the bin folders in my `SCM` (subversion).

How do I setup my "Artifacts to copy" and "target location" boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Build triggers` inside the `project A` config. You can check the `Build after other projects are built` specifying the `B`, `C` and `D` projects.

Then you can add a step in the `project A` build process, adding a `command` you can execute a `shell script` copying the needed files from projects `B`, `C` and `D` inside the `project A` just before the build starts.